# xbindkeys wont recognise keypress

Tags: linux, keyboard, gnome, xorg, xbindkeys

I am using Fedora Gnome on a tablet hybrid. I've written a script which uses xrandr to rotate the screen and I'd like to bind it to one of laptop's useless side-panel buttons, currently the one which has a "windows" sticker next to it. Predictably, Gnome interprets this as "super" key.

Here is the output of various commands:

```
# showkey -s
0xe0 0x5b 0xe0 0xdb

# showkey -a
```

(No output)

```
# showkey -k
keycode 125 press
keycode 125 release

$ xev
KeymapNotify event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x0
keys: 2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

I have tried mapping .xbindkeysrc like this:

```
"/usr/local/bin/rotatescreen.sh"
    m:0xdb + c:125
```

However, nothing changes even after I run xbindkeys.

Here's what happens with the same sequence of commands, when I hold the actual super key instead:

```
$ xev
KeymapNotify event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x0
keys: 2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

# showkey -k
keycode 125 press
keycode 125 release

# showkey -s
0xe0 0x5b 
0xe0 0xdb

# showkey -a
```

(No output)

How can I bind my useless side key to my rotate my screen script?

Answer (score 2):

Execute in the terminal: 
`xbindkeys -k`

A blank window will pop up. Press the key(s) to which you wish to assign a command and xbindkeys will output a handy snippet that can be entered into `~/.xbindkeysrc`

Citing https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys

According to your xev output, I think the states and keycodes for your system might be:

`m:0x0 + c:36`

Comment: Thanks for that, unfortunately xbindkeys -k produces no output when I press that key in the window. I tried your snippet in .xbindkeysrc and then reloaded the file using xbindkeys (no arguments). Unfortunately, it doesn't produce the desired result...

Comment: I looked into it a bit further and it seems like keycode 36 *is* normally the winkey, which means that the system might always interpret it as such, i.e. you can't have that button do something unique. With `m:0x0 + c:36` in the `~/.xbindkeysrc`, what does pushing your winkey do by the way? Are you sure your script works? Have you tried assigning it to some other key combination?
xmodmap is another fine utility, that makes it possible to remap keys, that might also be useful for your project.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this Mikkel. They win key continues to act as super (engages gnome activities) when m:0x0 + c:36 is added to .xbindkeysrc. The enter key activates the screen rotate script. :-( But at least I know the script works!!!

Comment: This command exactly gave me what I wanted. Thanks alot!!! I binded my Super key which wasn't binded at all. No programs were giving me correct code, this helped me and I binded my Super key using xmodmap.